# Is it possible to set curl.cainfo for my website on a remote server when I don't have access to php.ini?

Tags: php, curl

I have set curl.cainfo on my local server due to an issue I had.

I have updated the pem file and it fixed also some issues I had with the script.

My question is, is it possible to set curl.cainfo for my website on a remote server when I don't have access to php.ini?

Comment: No, but you can probably set that value or the CA cert a number of different ways.

Comment: I can change it under SSL on the cPanel but they require crt file.